# how to add space after symbol while I'm typing in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, space

I want to add space to separate symbols when writing code. And I'm using Sublime Text 2

For example the code A is better than B:

A:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = {'name': 'Tom', 'age': 23}
c = 12 + 23 - 1
```

B:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b={'name':'Tom','age':23}
c=12+23-1
```

But I have to type a lot of space, which is very boring.

In **Sublime Text 2**, how can I do this **automatically** when typing? Or is there any suggested plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think a plugin/package exists, but this regex will do your general case:

Find

```
':|=|,|\+|\-|([a-z0-9])(?=[=|\+|\-])'
```

Replace all

```
'$& '
```

Do not include the single quotes `'`

btw, find/replace is `cmd + alt + f` on a mac